# Como posso distribuir o programa .py sem que o usuário tenha que ficar instalando todas as bibliotecas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo Python e preciso distribuir um programa, li sobre o cx_Freeze e o py2exe para gerar um .exe. Porém, não me importo em distribuir o código do programa junto, logo, não vejo necessidade em gerar um .exe.

Como posso distribuir o programa .py sem que o usuário tenha que ficar instalando todas as bibliotecas utilizadas no programa? Posso criar um instalador?

Comment: Seria interessante você abrir outra pergunta com relação a proteção da senha, mesmo que se trate do processo de distribuição e python, assim você pode ter ajuda de mais pessoas e respostas mais diretas.

Comment: Já tirei a última pergunta.

Answer (score 11):

Bom, não sei se isso é possível, mas talvez você possa fazer isso para facilitar a instalação dos pacotes:

Usando um arquivo **.bat** você pode instalar as bibliotecas usando pip, por exemplo:

```
start /w pip install numpy 
start /w pip install matplotlib
start /w pip install qualquerOutraBiblioteca
...
```

Se for preciso colocar o pip no caminho do sistema, antes do código acima, coloque:

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python33\Scripts"
```

Se for preciso instalar o pip, coloque antes de tudo:

```
start /w python get-pip.py
```

---

Link para [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

[Sobre](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(gerenciador_de_pacotes)) o pip.

---

Se quieser gerar um instalador **.msi**, dá uma olhada em [pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Note que essa abordagem no entanto, restringe a distribuição à sistemas Windows. O processo que descrevo abaixo gera um instalador completo para Windows, mas pode dar saída para outras plataformas também. O processo que exige interação manual, com a criação do arquivo "requirements.txt" também é multiplataforma.

Answer (score 9):

Python tem um ecosistema de gerenciamento de pacotes (as bibliotecas) integrado tanto à linguagem, quanto em pacotes próprios.

O PIP - uma ferramenta tão necessária que passou a ser parte das novas instalações de Python a partir do Python 3.3 resolve de forma manual a questão das dependências para quem está com pressa e não quer deixar o pacote redondinho para terceiros.

Claro, tudo isso assume que o seu projeto já esteja rodando num virtualenv separado, em que as únicas bibliotecas instaladas além do seu próprio projeto são as que você quer garantir que estejam instaladas no destino.

Se você ainda não está usando o Virtualenv para o seu desenvolvimento, dê uma olhada aqui:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ (ou, para Python >= 3.3 o venv, que vem junto com o Python): https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Nesse caso, você pode usar o PIP para criar um arquivo com a lista das bibliotecas de Python instaladas no seu projeto - digite:
`pip freeze >requirements.txt` 
no terminal, com o virtualenv ativado. Isso vai listar automaticamente as bibliotecas instaladas no arquivo "requirements.txt" -- quem for instalar o seu programa, depois de ter o código na mão, e criar o virtualenv, deve digitar:
`pip -r requirements.txt`.

Desenvolvedores Python acostumados a pegar e colocar projetos em sites como o github saberão instalar pacotes e bibliotecas seguindo essa recomendação.

Mas, isso não responde sua pergunta - se você quer que um usuário leigo possa instalar seu programa, tendo apenas o Python instalado, isso é possível sim - mas dá um pouco mais de trabalho para acertar na primeira vez, para o desenvolvedor.

Você vai fazer uso então do "setuptools" - um pacote de Python feito para, a partir de informações sobre o seu projeto que você coloca num arquivo de nome `setup.py` - Esse arquivo é um pequeno programa em Python onde você coloca não só as dependências do seu projeto, (como instruções de compilação de módulos, se houver parte do projeto em C ou Cython),  metadados sobre número da versão do projeto, autor, e licença de uso e assim por diante.

O setuptools faz com que o `setup.py` funcione como uma aplicação completa de linha de comando, com várias opções. Uma delas inclusive é chamar direto
`python setup.py bdist_wininst`  - que num ambiente Windows configurado corretamente vai gerar um arquivo .EXE que instala sua aplicação e os requisitos dela (só não instala o Python - como o pyfreeze e outros utilitários fazem).

Agora o setuptools é usado, mais normalmente, não para criar instaláveis para Windows - e sim - para colocar o seu projeto, uma vez testado e preenchendo alguns requisitos de qualidade, direto no Pypi - o "Python Package Index". 
A partir daí, qualquer pessoa com Python e o Pip (ou easy_install) instalado vai poder instalar o seu projeto simplesmente digitando:
"pip install  "  (e, sim, isso instala o seu projeto e as bibliotecas de que ele depende).
Para programadores e usuários de Python acaba sendo mais prático do que ter um instalador em algum site web - você não tem que achar o site, baixar o arquivo, e executá-lo - basta digitar o comando. (E também seu projeto passa a integrar a lista de projetos que podem ser requisitos de outros).

Para o público leigo que for instalar, por exemplo, um jogo feito com Pygame, a forma com instalador de Windows é certamente mais conveniente.

A documentação do setuptools é algo que realmente vale a pena estudar se você quer distribuir seus projetos para o público em geral, sejam usuários finais ou mesmo para a comunidade de programadores Python. Comece pelo link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [`zipapp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) nas versões 3.5+.

## TL;DR

Vamos supor que eu irei fazer uma aplicação que consulta uma API de usuários. Para isso precisaremos do pacote `requests`.

Teremos o diretório da aplicação:

```
⊦ users/
    ⊦ venv/
    ⊦ users/
        ⊦ app.py
    ⊦ requirements.txt
```

Para isso, criamos o diretório:

```
$ mkdir users %% cd $_
```

Iniciamos um ambiente virtual:

```
$ python3.6 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Instalamos o pacote `requests`:

```
$ pip install requests
```

E geramos o arquivo `requirements.txt`:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Assim, podemos escrever a nossa aplicação. Para fins de exemplo, utilizarei a API https://reqres.in/api/users e solicitaremos ao usuário qual é a página de usuários que ele deseja listar. Assim, nosso código ficará:

```
# users/app.py

import requests

API = 'https://reqres.in/api/users'

def main():
    while True:
        page = input('Digite o número da página: ')
        params = {'page': page}
        response = requests.get(API, params=params)

        if response.ok:
            data = response.json()
            if data['data']:
                for user in data['data']:
                    print(f'#{user["id"]}: {user["first_name"]} {user["last_name"]}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Podemos testá-la localmente fazendo:

```
$ python users/app.py
Digite o número da página: 1
#1: George Bluth
#2: Janet Weaver
#3: Emma Wong
```

Perfeito. Funcionando. Agora desejamos empacotar essa nossa aplicação para compartilhar com outros usuários.

Primeiro, instalamos as dependências da aplicação diretamente no próprio diretório, de modo que ela fique autocontida. Para isso, basta-nos executar:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --target users
```

Com as dependências instaladas localmente podemos criar o arquivo de distribuição a partir do pacote `zipapp`:

```
$ python -m zipapp -m 'app:main' users
```

Isso irá criar o arquivo `users.pyz`, que pode ser executado diretamente do Python e já possuindo todas as dependências da aplicação. Ou seja, basta enviar este arquivo para os outros usuários e eles executarem:

```
$ python users.pyz
Digite o número da página: 1
#1: George Bluth
#2: Janet Weaver
#3: Emma Wong
Digite o número da página: 2
#4: Eve Holt
#5: Charles Morris
#6: Tracey Ramos
```

A opção `-m` do `zipapp` definirá a porta de entrada da aplicação, por isso definimos ela como `app:main`, isto é, módulo `app.py`, função `main`.

Mas vale lembrar que isso apenas empacotará sua aplicação e as respectivas dependências dentro de um arquivo compactado. Isso consequentemente deixará o arquivo maior e não ofuscará o código fonte, tanto que é possível abrir diretamente o arquivo `users.pyz`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de distribuir pacotes em Python muito similar ao que o java faz com os arquivos `.jar` são [Eggs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_(Python)). Desta maneira o usuário poderá rodar seu programa com:

```
$ python program.egg
```

Sem se procupar com as dependências, que podem ser empacotadas junto com o seu programa. Recomendo que procure uma leitura sobre [como criar eggs](http://blog.tiveron.mitgnu.com/2011/02/criando-um-python-egg/).